# Add constants to start and end of "file" after multiple replacements

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have already found how to do multiple replacements, bu replacing

`(from1)|(from2).....`

with

`(?1to1)(?2to2)`

For example, if I have:

`hello all! I think saying hello to all is a nice way to introduce oneself.`

and I replace

`(hello)|(all)`

with

`(?1greetings)(?2everyone)`

I get

`greetings everyone! I think saying greetings to everyone is a nice way to introduce oneself.`

Now, I want to add a string at the very beginning and end of file - not each line. So, in that case, my desired result is:

`StartOfAllgreetings everyone! I think saying greetings to everyone is a nice way to introduce oneself.EndOfAll`

Can you help me with this? Things that I have tried unsuccesfully include using $,\z,\Z to identify the end of line, and using branch reset groups like this (?|(hello)|(all))*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

Find What: `(^)(?<!(?s:.))|(hello)|(all)|($)(?!(?s:.))`
Or with *`.` matches newline* **ON**: `(^)(?<!.)|(hello)|(all)|($)(?!.)`
Replace with: `(?1StartOfAll)(?2greetings)(?3everyone)(?4EndOfAll)`

**NOTE**: In order to also handle the end of file match when another alternative also matches at the end of the file, you need to add optional groups and handle them in the replacement pattern, too:

**Find What**: `(?s)(^)(?<!.)|(hello)(?:($)(?!.))?|(all)(?:($)(?!.))?|($)(?!.)`
**Replace with**: `(?1StartOfAll)(?2greetings)(?3EndOfAll)(?4everyone)(?5EndOfAll)(?6EndOfAll)`

Now, the `(?:($)(?!.))?` optional non-capturing groups ensure an additional capture for end of file positions, and that is why there are additional `(?nEndOfAll)` in the replacement pattern.

**Details**

The `(^)(?<!(?s:.))|(hello)|(all)|($)(?!(?s:.))` has four alternatives, the ones that you are interested are

- `(^)(?<!(?s:.))` - The first alternative and the start of file is matched (and captured into Group 1) with `^` that is not preceded with any char (ensured with a negative lookbehind `(?<!.)` - the inline modifier group is added to make sure the regex works regardless of extra regex Notepad++ settings)
- `($)(?!(?s:.))` - matches (and captures into Group 4) the end of line that is not followed with any char (see the `(?!(?s:.))` negative lookahead).

*Settings & demo*:

[image]

Comment: This works! I will have a few questions. For one, I have not seen the semicolon(:) in the docs until now, what does it do?

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis See [Modifier spans](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html#spans) and [Combining Non-Capture Group with Inline Modifiers](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#nocap-with-modifier).

Comment: Here is what the trouble is: if one of the replacement words is at the end (just add a "hello" to the end of my initial string), the replacement kind of consumes(??) the $, and I won't get the EndOfAll at the end.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis Then there is no other way than `(^)(?<!(?s:.))|(hello)(?:($)(?!.))?|(all)(?:($)(?!.))?|($)(?!(?s:.))` > `(?1StartOfAll)(?2greetings)(?3EndOfAll)(?4everyone)(?5EndOfAll)(?6EndOfAll)` with *`.` matches newline* **ON**.

Comment: Painful, but correct. Can you please include this to your answer so I can tick it?